# how can i make my iphone app to Supporting Multiple iOS Versions and Devices in swift programmatically using device screen size

Tags: swift

Here i try this swift code for to make support all versions and devices but it not works otherwise it shown black display on simulator.

```
 var systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion;


    if(ver >= 7)

    {

        NSLog("Version number above 6");                      

        let screenWidth = self.view.bounds

        let screenHeight = self.view.bounds


        if ((screenSize.width == 320.00) && (screenSize.height == 480.00))          

        //Modify for 5 Screen Size

        if((screenSize.width == 320.00) && (screenSize.height == 568.00))

        {

            NSLog("6+ Device");

            self.view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 503, 320, 50)) // To allign bottom buttons

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use auto layout to support all devices screen size [link](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code), A app it can support default all version. Are you using which version of xcode? If you are using 6.1.1 then It support 4.3 to upto 8.1,So don't think about it.

Comment: Here i want to do via Programmatically so dont using auto layout and constraints..

Comment: yes, you can do auto layout programmatically. refer the above link. with out Auto Layout you can not compatible with iPhone any device, iPad any device, and iPod touch any device.

Comment: It s not that easy you can learn a auto layout in a day, you can refer the basic links [link] (http://www.digistarters.com/swift-auto-layout/), [link] (http://www.digistarters.com/swift-auto-layout/ ,[link] (http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code).

Comment: OH OK,Thank you nisar.